# How to programmatically open several pages in webview subsequently

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to open a website in Kotlin and login programmatically to it. Then I want to open different pages of that website programmatically and read their information using JavaScript and save them in some variables in Kotlin.

So far, I have used web-view and I can login to website programmatically using following code:

```
var webview = WebView(this)
     webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
     webview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
     webview.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
           webview.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
                 "document.getElementById('TXT_UserName').value = '" + password + "';" +
                 "document.getElementById('TXT_Password').value = '" + password + "';" +
                 "var frms = document.getElementById('btn_Login').click(); };")
             }
           })
        }
      }
     webview.loadUrl("http://10.104.24.64/")
```

I know by using **onPageFinished** function,I can understand when the first page is loaded completely. But I don't know when other pages are loaded completely. This is important to me because before completely loading, I can't read their information and JavaScript returns null. Also I don't know exactly how to open a link to other page from the first page programmatically. Following code is executed in JavaScript successfully, but in Kotlin returns null.

```
val script = "var t= document. getElementById ('ContentPlaceHold');" 
    +"t.name"
webview. evaluateJavascript(script,     object : ValueCallback<String> {
    override fun  onReceiveValue(value: String) {
      //to save JavaScript variables in to       Kotlin variables here
      }
      })
```

I think it's reason is that in Kotlin codes are executed asynchronously.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you do that?  Just put a link in your page, and then the webview will go there when they click it.  You don't do it for the webview.

Comment: My app should scan the pages automatically and a human is not supposed to click it.

Comment: If your app is scanning things for data, then you should either be using a webservice instead of a webpage (if you own the page), or a scraper instead of using a webview.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't own the page so probably I should use a scraper like Jsoup. Now, I have solved my problem by using two web views. One of them is used for login and it shows the first page of web. The second one is not shown and is used for scanning the pages. Do you think it is better to use Jsoup instead of this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Gabe Sechan**, I solved it with **Jsoup scraper**.